# Android child fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am programing an app in android studio.  My app uses fragments connected to a viewpager to display settings for various modules, one module per page.  Modules are hardware devices.  I would like to add a spinner to the top of the fragment so that when a user selects an item, the config options below the spinner change(ie. a different layout with radio buttons and options)for that specific module.  I designed different fragment layouts for different selections. But I ended up in context hell when I attempted to use multiple fragments per viewpage.  I want to be clear, I am not attempting to nest fragments, but use a header fragment (with the spinner on it) and a detail fragment below the header with the module options displayed.  Because I am using the viewpager I am (to my knowledge) forced to use the support library.

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible (header & detail fragments on one viewpage) or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use nested fragments for this problem, but either way I would use a different viewpager for your heading fragment than for your details fragment :).
From how I understand your question, it seems that you have several different heading fragments, and then each heading fragment would have a unique set of details pages which would only appear under this heading. Is this correct?
If this is the case, I would create each heading fragment with its own unique viewpager for the details fragments that correspond to that fragment, and renember to use the ChildFragmentManager for the details viewpager, as you will otherwise run into more problems :).
(E.g. something like the following in the fragment code for each heading:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_fragment, container, false); 
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.details_view_pager); 
    mAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()); 
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);     
    return mView; 
}
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Quite the opposite actually!  I have one header fragment with the spinner on it.  Once a item is selected, the appropriate details fragment should appear.  Both fragments (header and detail) are within individual frames on a separate fragment that is on one viewpager.